# GParted can't make new partition by resizing

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted

I'm trying to install a partition on Windows, but when I try to resize the partition I have for Ubuntu, it just doesn't let me resize it to make a new partition, I've unlocked the key and everything, but I don't know why it doesn't let me.

I've tried doing unmount `/dev/sda5` too,  but it says it's not mounted.

The same happens with its parent partition `sda2`.

I'm trying this from LIVE CD. Any idea on what can I do? I don't want to delete my Ubuntu system and it's not using all those 478Gb at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## WARNING: BACKUP ANY IMPORTANT DATA BEFORE MODIFYING PARTITIONS!

## /dev/sda5 "looks" full (because it's not a regular partition)

- you can't make it smaller unless you delete some stuff
- you can't make it larger because it's already at its largest size, based on disk size
- it's in an extended partition
- there's no room to add a partition for Windows
- its part of a lvm set

Your disk partition /dev/sda5 is part of a lvm set, and as such, you need to use lvm utilities to manage it. Install `system-config-lvm`, and start `Logical Volume Management` from the Unity dashboard to resize lvm partitions. Or use the `Disks` application, which is already installed in Ubuntu, and on the Ubuntu Live DVD.

## Logical Volume Management

in `terminal`:

- type `sudo apt-get update`
- type `sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm`
- quit terminal
- open the Unity dashboard
- type `lvm`
- start `Logical Volume Management`

## alternative Logical Volume Management

- it was just pointed out that the `Disks` application supports lvm directly. Just start it from the Unity dashboard. It's also available on the Ubuntu Live DVD. It may be even easier to use than `Logical Volume Management`... but install it anyway, 'cause it's kind of fun to see it visually.

Comment: Note that the Disks utility does support LVMs.

Comment: @muru I did not know that. Now I do! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the reason I mentioned Disks is that it's installed by default, and also available by default on live Ubuntu

Comment: @muru Excellent. Noted in the answer.

Comment: what's the use of deleting stuff if it's not full? will that LVM let me resize it?

Comment: When I first looked at your posted image, I thought, like most "normal" disks, it's obvious why the user can't do what they want to do. Then when I looked closer, I saw the "lvm2 pv" which designates a "lvm physical volume", and then I added the info about lvm management. And yes, those two tools will allow you to manage the lvm and resize it. Backup your data and try them.

Comment: Also KDE Partition Manager 3.0 supports LVM... You can try it from neon developer cd (and install it via sudo apt install partitionmanager). Here is a short demonstration of LVM resize capabilities: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKCQ7pJN1vY)